# The difference between 일 and 한 to mean "one"?

Tags: word-choice, numeral

It seems that one month, one week, and one year in Korean are the following:

> 한 달 (one month)
>
> 한 주 (one week)
>
> 일 년 (one year)

Why do the first two use '한' while the last one uses '일'? And how can I classify them if I encounter a new word?

Comment: Welcome to Korean Stack Exchange. I just edited your question to change '넨' to '년'.

Comment: @Rathony Oops. Sorry I should have double-checked it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's complicated... sometimes you can even use both and it changes either the meaning or style of speech.

The book [*Using Korean*](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=2ggVsnUCbiAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=using%20korean&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) devotes an entire chapter (about 9 pages) to this topic. Read the full details and numerous examples starting from page 169.

I'll try to summarize below (all quotes from *Using Korean*, examples have been greatly abridged):

## General summary

> In most cases, there is a strict division of labor in the use of
>   native Korean numbers and Sino-Korean numbers. For example, native
>   Korean numbers are used for counting (small numbers) and for o'clock
>   (세시 "3 o'clock"), while Sino-Korean numbers are employed for minutes,
>   dates, months, years, money, and so forth (16 절지 '8.5 by 11 size
>   paper', 24 금 '24 K gold', and so on).

> In some cases, both types of numbers can occur with the same counter,
>   creating sharp contrasts in meaning.

- 다섯 번 *five times*  (quantity)
- 오 번  *number 5* (order)

> Very rarely, either number can be used for the same concept, but this
>   is correlated with a contrast in speech style.

- 스무 살 *20 years old* (colloquial)
- 이십 세 *20 years old* (written/formal)

---

## Counting

> Native numerals are used for counting smaller units. For larger
>   quantities, Sino-Korean numerals are used, often in combination with
>   native numbers. There is a tendency for Sino-Korean numbers to be used
>   for multiples of 10, starting from 20, even when there is a native
>   Korean counterpart.

- 1: 종이 한 장 *one sheet of paper*
- 10: 종이 열 장
- 20: 종이 스무 장 or 이십 장
- 125: 종이 백 스물 다섯 장 or 백 이십 오 장

---

## Units of measurement

> Sino-Korean numbers are used for the metric system as well as some
>   American units of measurement. Native numbers are employed only for a
>   few traditional Korean units of measurement.

## Time, date, and age

> Both native and Sino-Korean numerals can be used for times, dates, and
>   ages. A particularly notorious case involves telling time, which
>   requires a native number for o'clock but a Sino-Korean number for
>   minutes.

[image]

---

## Arithmetic and fractions

> Sino-Korean numbers are used for arithmetical calculation, fractions
>   (분수), decimals (소수), and multiplication tables (구구단). But native
>   numbers are used for numerical comparison in general.

---

## Money and Currency, Numbers relating to transportation

> Sino-Korean numbers are used.

Answer (score 1):

일 is not quantitative, in other words you should use 일 whenever you are not counting. So for example, telephone numbers, IDs, use 일 instead of 한.

Example: 일 항 -> paragraph one

한 is opposite, it is used only when you are counting.

Example: 한 마디 -> one sentence,

한 사람 -> one person

However, if there is no counter, use 하나 instead. Ex: 하나 있다 -> There is one

There are some exceptions, when 일 is used instead of 한(하나): 년, 초, 분, 주, 일, 개월.

There are still some others, but rarely will it happen, so just memorize them if you encounter one.

So in your example, 한 주 is wrong, but 일 주.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Here's one more: "일인분" (one serving). I thought it was Chinese words are paired with Chinese numbers, but the example in the question (주) threw me off...

Comment: @Leftium If you say Chinese words paired with Chinese numbers, then I can give you many exceptions: 한번(番), 한명(名), 한개(個), 한곡(曲),한장(張),...